# Serialise object - GetProperties() causes stack overflow?

Tags: c#, serialization, sharepoint

I'm trying to serialise all the properties of an object that by default cannot be serialised (the object is of type SPGroup which is sealed and has no empty constructor) so I'm copying all of the properties from the object which I will then serialise.

I get the data from the properties with the code below:

```
private dynamic GetSerializableProperties<T>(T objToCopy, dynamic dataContainer = null)
{
    // Copy the properties into dataContainer, if it's not set
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, dataContainer))
    {
        dataContainer = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, object>;
    }
    // copy base class properties.
    var objToCopyType = objToCopy.GetType();
    foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in objToCopyType.GetProperties())
    {

        // Get the correct property
        PropertyInfo propertyInfoValue = objToCopyType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name);
        // Get the value of the property
        var value = objToCopyType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).GetValue(objToCopy, null); // propertyInfoValue.GetValue(objToCopy, null);
        // Create the ID for the dictionary, set to name/random string for easy viewing
        string propertyKeyName = CreateSafeName(dataContainer, propertyInfo.Name);

        // Create a property with the required name then add data
        ((IDictionary<String, Object>)dataContainer)[propertyInfo.Name] = new DataContainer(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo, propertyInfoValue, value);
    }
    return dataContainer;
}
```

When I look into the dynamic object I've created I see all the properties I want i.e. the Property Users contains a list of users. The next step is serialising this data which is where the error occurs.

```
dynamic serializableObject = GetSerializableProperties<T>(serializableObjectx);
var test = serializableObject as IDictionary<string, Object>;
var test2 = test.Values.ElementAt(2) as DataContainer; // This property contains a property that is causing the issue I believe
var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test2, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

The error I get is:

```
Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.
```

I believe the code below this comment needs to be changed:

```
var value = objToCopyType.GetProperty(propertyInfo.Name).GetValue(objToCopy, null); // propertyInfoValue.GetValue(objToCopy, null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right you are trying to serialize sharepoint objects? Most of the time it will end in a circulation.

SPGroup.Users -> SPUser.Groups -> SPGroup.Users -> ...

So the serializer will run in a infinite loop or a stack overflow. The better way will be building your own objects without some of the properties which leads to a circle.

Comment: Hi, you are correct. I decided to stop it going more than one level deep